# How can I add a string-array with website URL to a ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've added a string array to my Android app for the credits of people that have worked it. 
Each item has the construction of `<item>role,name,website url</item>` 
I want to post each item in a scroll view like so:

```
role1 
name
url

role2
name
url
```

But I'm not sure how to do this.
Can I do this directly in the layout XML file?
If not, how can I do this in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pure XML solution, use a `<string>` with new lines instead of `<string-array>`.

strings.xml:

```
<string name="multiline_text">
Philip J. Fry
\nDelivery Boy
\nhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fry_%28Futurama%29
\n
\nTuranga Leela
\nCaptain
\nhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leela_%28Futurama%29
</string>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:text="@string/multiline_text"
  android:autoLink="web"/>
```

`android:autoLink="web"` makes the links clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HTML String in your strings.xml file that contains all the data and use a TextView within a ScrollView to display it:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.my_string));
```

Alternatively, you could use a ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter that contains elements of your data type. Here's an example:

Employee.java:

```
public class Employee {
    String role, name, url;
}
```

EmployeeAdapter.java:

```
public class EmployeeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Employee> {
    private int mResource;

    public EmployeeAdapter(FindPenguinsActivity activity, int resource) {
        super(activity, resource);
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mResource, null);
        }

        // You should use the ViewHolder pattern here, this is just for simplicity
        TextView role = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.role);
        TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView url = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.url);

        Employee employee = getItem(position);
        role.setText(employee.role);
        role.setText(employee.name);
        role.setText(employee.url);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

employee.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/role"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/website"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now you can add the Adapter to a ListView:

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list); // Use the id of your ListView in the activity's xml layout file here

List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>(3);

// add Employee objects to the list

EmployeeAdapter adapter = new EmployeeAdapter(this, R.layout.employee);
adapter.addAll(employeeList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```